# Run Control-M job with a script that is stored in a GitLab repository

Tags: git, gitlab, control-m

is it possible to run a job in Control-M that accesses a (e.g. DB2) script stored in a Git repository?

Normally it is the case that you specify a path where the script is located. How would this look like when working with a remote Git repository? Is there a way to do this, or what could be a solution for this?